# NSClassFromString return nil for Bundle.main.infoDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am implementing my UITabBarController programmaticaly and I have an error when trying to retrieve my controllers from Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"]

Here is the code of the UITabBarController:

```
import UIKit

class ENTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addChildViewControllers()
    }

    fileprivate func addChildViewControllers() {
        addChildViewController("ENSwipeViewController", imageName: "TabBar_swipe_")
        addChildViewController("ENSocialViewController", imageName: "TabBar_social_")
        addChildViewController("ENNotificationViewController", imageName: "TabBar_notification_")

    }

    fileprivate func addChildViewController(_ childControllerName: String, imageName: String) {
        let ns = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String

        let cls: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString(ns + "." + childControllerName)

        let vcClass = cls as! UIViewController.Type
        let vc = vcClass.init()


        vc.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        vc.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: imageName + "selected")

        let nav = UINavigationController()
        nav.addChildViewController(vc)
        addChildViewController(nav)
    }
}
```

Error happens at `let vcClass = cls as! UIViewController.Type` and is:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Here is the simple code of the ENSwipeViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ENSwipeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you took a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395135-nsclassfromstring) you would see that it says:

> **Return Value**
>
> The class object named by aClassName, ***or nil if no class by that name
>   is currently loaded***. If aClassName is nil, returns nil.

So since your `ENSwipeViewController` is not yet loaded it returns nil...

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by attempting to force unwrap the optional value `cls`. Which is type **AnyObject.type** So, Adding the following lines of code to your func will fix your issue.

#### addChildViewController

```
let vcClassArray: [UIViewController.Type] = [
    ENSwipeViewController.self
]
let vcClass = classArray[0] // we only have one value 
                        // if you have more you could simply make this a variable
let vc = vcClass.init()
```

These lines above replace what you have here in the same func.

```
let vcClass = cls as! UIViewController.Type
let vc = vcClass.init()
```

You will need to convert the `AnyClass?`to the Class you are segueing to and `init` using `vcClass.init()`

Comment: The fact that you force unwrap doesn't mean it's the cause of the nil optional.

Comment: @Lefteris That is true, but it crashes because the force cast to ViewController.type always fails, because cls holds nil. Since the value `ENSwipeViewController` isn't loaded as you've otlined.